# How to run scripts more than 15 mins in app engine

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

So i wrote a node script which fetches data from WP.org themes/plugins. The theme script will take around 4-5 hours to complete ( scraping and inserting data into BigQuery ).
The problem arises when i used google app engine to deploy the script, it works fine for 15 mins then it stops. Any way to increase the execution time of scripts in app engine.

These scripts will run weekly or every fortnight and will run until they are done. But app engine stops them after 15 mins. They works fine on my localhost so its not issue with node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max allowed run-time of a request is based on your selected scaling type. So it sounds like you will need to create a separate service to run this task with **Basic** or **Manual** set for the scaling type

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_types

You could also try breaking up your task into multiple 10 minute tasks and chain them together

Comment: It's not about a request , it's about max execution time alloted for a script . And yeah I know it's possible to Break it and chain it but it will take more time then.

Comment: perhaps there's something I'm not getting. How is this "script" not a request? I imagine you are trying to kick-off this job via cron, which comes in as a request into app engine. What does that request handler then do?

Comment: If this is a request to app engine and I'm on automatic scaling right now then why is the execution time is more than 10 mins as stated in the documentation ?

Comment: then how is this script getting triggered / run? some example code would be helpful

Comment: I'm calling it via cloud scheduler right now

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/62751234/4458510 There is an --attempt-deadline param you can set to remove any issues with cloud scheduler killing your task, but after that you are at the mercy of the max timeout of your target (which in your case is App Engine). I dont know how you're getting away with running for 15 minutes instead of 10. I think Cloud Run has a 15 minute timeout.

Comment: ill try this thing and let you know and yes its weird that im getting 15mins time not 10mins